# Referencing mapped child observables with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I would like to be able to map the incoming data down to the child objects and their observable arrays and access observables in child objects (in this example: Main -> BikeShop().BikeShopExtra()).

It seems I can have one or the other, but not both. In the example below, it fails on this line of the Main object.

```
self.MainTest = ko.observable(self.BikeShop().BikeShopExtra());
```

The structure I am going for is this:
  App - Initializes Main
  Main - Contains all of the business logic, similar to a controller in MVC pattern 
  BikeShop and Customer - DTOs, similar to a view model in MVC pattern

I have a broken skeleton example of the issue I am having:
https://jsfiddle.net/Mason240/36gh20p8/52/

```
window.Application = window.Application || { Config: {}, Models: { }, Mappings: { } };

window.Application.App = (function ($, ko) {

    var init = function (opts) {
       var vm = new Application.Models.Main();
       ko.mapping.fromJS(opts.model, Application.Mappings.Main, vm);
       ko.applyBindings(vm);
    };

    return {
        Init: init
    };

}(jQuery, ko));

window.Application.Models.Main = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.BikeShop = ko.observable();
    self.MainTest = ko.observable(self.BikeShop().BikeShopExtra());
};

window.Application.Models.BikeShop = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.StoreName = ko.observable();
    self.Customers = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.CompoundId = ko.computed({
      read: function () {
        return self.Id() + "-" + self.StoreName();
      }
    });
    self.BikeShopExtra = ko.observable("Bike Shop Extra");
};

window.Application.Models.Customer = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.Name = ko.observable();
    self.CompoundId = ko.computed({
      read: function () {
        return self.Id() + "-" + self.Name();
      }
    });
  self.CustomerExtra = ko.observable("Customer Extra");
};

window.Application.Mappings.Main = {
    'BikeShop': {
        create: function (obj) {
            var model = new Application.Models.BikeShop();
            ko.mapping.fromJS(obj.data, Application.Mappings.BikeShop, model);
            return model;
        }
    }
};

window.Application.Mappings.BikeShop = {
    'Customers': {
        key: function (data) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Id);
        },
        create: function (obj) {
            var model = new Application.Models.Customer();
            if (obj.data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(obj.data, {}, model);
            }
            return model;
        }
    }
};

(function ($) {
  Application.App.Init({
    "model" : {
      "BikeShop": {
        "Id": 79605,
        "StoreName": "Valley Bike",
        "Customers": [
          {
            "Id": 54132123,
            "Name": "Greg"
          },
          {
            "Id": 78906344,
            "Name": "Mason"
          }]
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You can use a computed for your MainTest: `self.MainTest = ko.computed({
      read: function () {
        return self.BikeShop().BikeShopExtra();
      },
      deferEvaluation: true
    });`

Comment: In the code you've posted you're calling `self.BikeShop().BikeShopExtra()` right after declaring self.BikeShop, but you haven't given self.BikeShop a value yet so it's still undefined.

Comment: @nemesv, you're right. I had tried making it a computed value, but it didn't work because I was missing the `deferEvaluation: true` setting. Please submit as an answer and I can mark it resolved.